# в некоторых случаях некорректно указываются причины закрытия

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, модерация

при голосовании за закрытие вопроса не всегда все голосуют только за одну причину. пример [в очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/90787) ([сам вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/538457/178576)):

> объявлен вчера требующим правки пользователями alexander barakin, Streletz, kff, zRrr, D-side, так как не по теме
>
> Похоже, этот вопрос не соответствует тематике. Те, кто, голосовал за его закрытие, указывали следующие причины:
>
> - "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы до публикации вопроса." – alexander barakin, D-side
> - "Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример." – Streletz, kff, zRrr

как видим, в сообщении о закрытии перечислены две причины закрытия и приведена информация о том, кто за какую причину голосовал.

---

а вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/93116) ([сам вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/541532/178576)) я голосовал за закрытие последним (пятым), и (готовя почву для этого самого вопроса на мете) намеренно выбрал причиной **не** «дубликат» (как все четверо проголосовавших до меня). но в сообщении о закрытии написано, что якобы и я **тоже** проголосовал за причину «дубликат»:

> отмечен как дубликат пользователями pavlofff, D-side, Bald, cheops, alexander barakin 3 часа назад
>
> Такой вопрос задавали ранее и на него уже получен ответ. Если представленные ответы не являются исчерпывающими, пожалуйста задайте новый вопрос.

---

[ещё один пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/93269), где я тоже специально проголосовал (пятым) не за ту причину, по которой проголосовали остальные.

Comment: по моему уже был похожий вопрос, и все сводилось к весу голосов, если поровну(примерно) то несколько причин показывать, если намного больше - то наибольшую

Comment: @Grundy, у меня сложилось впечатление, что именно причина «дубликат» перекрывает все остальные. насколько мне помнится, я ни разу не встречал упоминаний (в прикрепленной «плашке») про иные причины, если вопрос закрыт как дубликат.

Comment: с дубликатом другая проблема была: в некоторых случаях можно увидеть **три** дублирующих вопроса в результате

Comment: А ещё если модератор закрывает, то используется указанная им причина, вне зависимости от остального расклада голосов. Но это вроде не баг.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну эт понятно. эт [tag:модераторский-произвол] // кстати, а модераторы могут посмотреть, кто как голосовал за закрытие?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, можем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сколько я понимаю, несколько причин закрытия вопроса отображаются в том случае, если участники голосования разделились во мнении на два лагеря (за одну проголосовали три участника, за другую два). В случае, если голосует модератор, будет выбрана та причина, которую выбрал модератор. Чтобы причина отображалась в списке, необходимо, чтобы она получила как минимум два голоса.

Если я верно понимаю, все выше сказанное справедливо для закрытия вопроса как «не по теме».

Список «закрывших» отображает участников, которые приняли участие в голосование.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194656/274323

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я помню, отображаются те причины, которые набрали хотя бы 2 голоса. Т. е. если вопрос закрыт с 5 разными причинами (а такой вопрос был и я даже спрашивал про него на мете), то не будет показана ни одна из них. Просто общие слова, что он не по теме.